# Approval workflow notification mail

Tags: workflow

I am customizing the existing approval workflow for my purchase order workflow. In that, I want a separate email notification sent when the "Change Request Form" is submitted. Now the same mail(sent on invocation of workflow) is sent. Is there a separate mail notification associated with "Change Request Form". Could anybody please help me with this?

Comment: how is this setup? Can you show what you did in SharePoint Designer?

Comment: Could you show us a screenshot of your workflow?

Comment: Thanks for your replies guys, but I decided to use single notification for Workflow invocation and for Change Request.